# Laravel Queue Job gives error Model not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue, jobs

I have created the job file and I'm dispatching the mail through the controller using mailable it will create the entry in job table but after the few seconds it will transfer the record into the failed_jobs table and gives error model not found

Controller Dispatch method

```
if (!empty($emails) && isset($result->email)) {
                dispatch(new SendNotificationEmailJob($emails, $result, 'WarehouseAddUpdate', array($subject, $request['number'], 'add')));
        }
```

SendNotificationEmailJob Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendNotificationEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $emails;
    protected $result;
    protected $mailClass;
    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($emails, $result, $mailClass, $data)
    {   
        $this->emails = $emails;
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->mailClass = 'App\Mail\\'.$mailClass;
        $this->data = $data;        
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {           
        if ($this->result == null) {
            if (!empty($this->emails)) {            
                $to = $this->emails[0];    
                unset($this->emails[0]);
            }
        }else{
            if($this->result != null && isset($this->result->email)){                
                $to = $this->result->email;
                if (($key = array_search($this->result->email, $this->emails)) !== false) {
                    unset($this->emails[$key]);
                }            
            }
        }

        if (!empty($this->emails) && isset($result->email)) { 
            $email = new $this->mailClass($this->data);           
            Mail::to($to)->cc($this->emails)->send($email);            
        }

        if (empty($emails) && isset($result->email)) {
            $email = new $this->mailClass($this->data);
            Mail::to($to)->send($email);
        }        
    }
}
```

Mailable Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class WarehouseAddUpdate extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The data object instance.
     *
     * @var data
     */
    public $subject;

    public $warehouse;

    public $type;

    public $oldstatus;

    public $newstatus;

    public $receiver;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->subject = $data[0];
        $this->warehouse = $data[1];
        $this->type = $data[2];
        $this->oldstatus = $data[3] ?? null;
        $this->newstatus = $data[4] ?? null;
        $this->receiver = 'Manager';
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mails.warehouseaddupdate')->subject($this->subject);
    }
}
```

this is my SendNotificationEmail Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendNotificationEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $emails;
    protected $result;
    protected $mailClass;
    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($emails, $result, $mailClass, $data)
    {   
        $this->emails = $emails;
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->mailClass = 'App\Mail\\'.$mailClass;
        $this->data = $data;        
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {           
        if ($this->result == null) {
            if (!empty($this->emails)) {            
                $to = $this->emails[0];    
                unset($this->emails[0]);
            }
        }else{
            if($this->result != null && isset($this->result->email)){                
                $to = $this->result->email;
                if (($key = array_search($this->result->email, $this->emails)) !== false) {
                    unset($this->emails[$key]);
                }            
            }
        }

        if (!empty($this->emails) && isset($result->email)) { 
            $email = new $this->mailClass($this->data);           
            Mail::to($to)->cc($this->emails)->send($email);            
        }

        if (empty($emails) && isset($result->email)) {
            $email = new $this->mailClass($this->data);
            Mail::to($to)->send($email);
        }        
    }
}
```

The error I found in DB failed_jobs table

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results
>   for model [App\Model\V1\User]. in
>   /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:416
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php(54):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->firstOrFail()
>
> ## 1 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesModels.php(41):
>
> App\Jobs\SendNotificationEmailJob->getRestoredPropertyValue(Object(Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier))
>
> ## 2 [internal function]: App\Jobs\SendNotificationEmailJob->__wakeup()
>
> ## 3 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(42):
>
> unserialize('O:33:"App\Jobs\...')
>
> ## 4 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(76):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob),
>   Array)
>
> ## 5 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(320):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
>
> ## 6 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(270):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database',
>   Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob),
>   Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> ## 7 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(114):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob),
>   'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> ## 8 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default',
>   Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> ## 9 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
>
> ## 10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
>
> ## 11 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29):
>
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> ## 12 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87):
>
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()
>
> ## 13 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31):
>
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application),
>   Array, Object(Closure))
>
> ## 14 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549):
>
> Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application),
>   Array, Array, NULL)
>
> ## 15 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
>
> ## 16 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252):
>
> Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>
> ## 17 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>
> ## 18 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(946):
>
> Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 19 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(248):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 20 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 21 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 22 /var/www/html/smartcgd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121):
>
> Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 23 /var/www/html/smartcgd/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 24 {main}

Comment: It's not giving model not found, it's giving `No query results for model` when you're using `firstOrFail()`. This means it could not find the user. `firstOrFail()` is not in this code, but is apparently triggered in `App\Jobs\SendNotificationEmailJob->__wakeup()`

Comment: but I'have not used the firstOrFail() in my model and also that this dispatch code is working fine with another model purchaseorder

Comment: It probably does work fine for the purchase order because it can find the record. But it's not finding the record for User in this one. Can you show the __wakeup() function that exists in either SendNotificationEmailJob or ShouldQueue?

Comment: I have added SendNotificationEmailJob class please check, and I checked __wakeup() function in my entire project that is only found in vendor files with default code I have not changed the signle line there. BTW thanks for doing such a efforts

Comment: Whoops, I missed a line. It seems to be called from `SendNotificationEmailJob->getRestoredPropertyValue` which I don't see here, either. You can also do a search for `User::firstOrFail` in your project to see where it might be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a model object within a Laravel job, the job relies on the object's ID to retrieve the corresponding model object. Laravel will display an error if the ID is not provided. Therefore, when passing an object to the job, ensure that the object's ID is included along with the object itself.